# Why did this highly insensitive question take 16 hours to close?

Tags: discussion

I would like an explanation why this question was not closed ASAP.

[No one ever hated their own body. Really?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/54864/no-one-ever-hated-their-own-body-really)

Answer (score 5):

### Why it wasn't closed earlier

This question took sixteen hours to close because not a single person - including those who flagged the Answer - voted to close it, or offered a corrective edit. Some Users took offense to the first Answer, but **nobody flagged the question as having any issues, or took any action to question or resolve it.**

As moderators we strive to remain highly cautious against taking unilateral action, especially in cases like this where many experienced users had already engaged with a Question and not perceived or flagged a problem. However, on this occasion the question did mention self-harm, which is a highly sensitive topic, and had solicited an answer on the same which had breached the Code of Conduct.

### Why it was closed

Though it was the Answer causing the perceived issues, penalising a user for trying to fully answer the question as it was presented did not seem entirely appropriate. **Considering that a full answer to the Question as-presented necessarily *needs* to verge onto modern application, and it was likely to attract similar answers if left Open, the fairest resolution was to edit the Answer to conform to the CoC and Close the question.**

The question in its original form does not take any evident interest in the text, its original context or author, and its sole declared basis for asking is: *"But many people today hate their bodies. Some even do self-harm and cut their bodies."*

### Avoiding situations like this in future

BH.SE is a community site and needs a community attitude to function well. As moderators we very much appreciate users flagging offensive content, and that is the right thing to do when you observe it. However, most users do not intentionally post offensive content, and often need some help understanding why there is a problem with their content. In this case it would have been better to see supportive and sensitive corrections from the community, for both the Question and the Answer.

It's hard to write good questions on sensitive topics, and for users who struggle to understand the sensitivities, I'd always recommend a healthy dose of mercy and compassion, and not just assuming that they are intentionally posting offensive content.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation.

Comment: There was a comment left by a user regarding the content of the question which advised the poster that his question could cause "pain" to certain people.I upvoted this comment,but unfortunately the comment was deleted before i could post it here.Did the moderators delete this comment? or was it the user who posted the comment that deleted it.

Comment: @Bagpipes - The comment was removed voluntarily after the question was closed, though it was certainly a good comment and upvoted by several others.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I don't think it warranted being closed - I don't think it so explicitly asks for contemporary application as Steve Taylor wrote. But I can see his point too, so I'm happy for it to be closed. If it gets edited to more clearly limit itself to direct exegesis of the passage then it can be reopened.

As to the content of the question, I don't think it is highly insensitive. It's true that today, as in the past, people self-harm (whether from mental illness or for religious reasons as in 1 Kings 18:28). There is an inherent tension between that and Paul's words.

Comment: Your a moderator and you dont think it warranted being closed.

Comment: @Bagpipes Maybe you could edit the question to explain why you think it does?

Comment: There is no need for me to edit the question.You closed this question here  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/54878/how-could-the-hebrews-migrate-out-from-egypt-to-canaan-if-canaan-belonged-to-eg 3 hours before you closed the highly insensitive question.The question in dispute is highly offensive.

Comment: @Bagpipes In your opinion. Which if you don't explain, then you can't complain if others don't see the offence you see.

Comment: The question has already been flagged as offensive.......I have removed three unnecessary references from the answer which are breaches of the SE Code of Conduct, and had already received two 'offensive' flags. The last paragraph of both Question and Answer verge onto modern applications anyway, which is off topic for this site, and so I'd suggest that a total removal of the paragraph would improve the quality of the answer. – Steve Taylor♦ 5 hours ago

Comment: @Bagpipes The **answer** was flagged as offensive. No one flagged the question. And Steve closed it for being a contemporary application question as I explained in my answer here, not because he thought the question was offensive.

Comment: The only thing I'd add here is that there appears to be a deeper misunderstanding in the question about the nature of self-harm, as it is a large and complex topic which [rarely has anything to do with hating your body](https://www.mentalhelp.net/suicide/6-reasons-why-people-self-injure/). For those who do not have friends or family who have suffered from this, it can be difficult to understand why concepts like this can be offensive or potentially harmful to others.

Comment: Some people suffering from eating disorders might say that they hate their bodies so it's not a totally inappropriate description.